# Rails 3.1.0 server crashes when trying to delete Association model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have the following models:

association.rb:

```rb
class Association < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :condominia, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :condominia, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

condominium.rb

```rb
class Condominium < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :association
  has_many :owners, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owners, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

owner.rb

```rb
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :condominium
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When I try to delete an Association model my rails server just crashes. 
Rails version 3.1.0 . And Ruby 1.9.2 p290
Any ideas why is this happening ?

Thanks.

UPDATE: If I try to remove the :dependent => :destroy it works. But because I need to create a batch of owners when a Condominium object is build I added:

```
def new_owners
    return 0
  end

  def new_owners=(int_num)
    int_num = int_num.to_i
    if int_num > 0
      int_num.times do
        self.owners.create
      end
    end
  end
```

The result is the same. Rails server crashing on save.

Comment: How does it crash? Any error message?

Comment: When you say delete an association, is it via the `_destroy` flag on one of the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` or deleting an `Association` from the `Condominium` model?  ie. `@condominium.association.destroy`. Any stack trace?

Comment: Can you show us the stack trace?

Comment: I delete an Association model with @association.destroy . Will come back with a stack trace, just 1 sec.

Comment: Destroying the `Association` would result in the `Condominium` being destroyed as well as the `Owner`.  If your table had any foreign keys on it, this could possibly be causing a problem, or one of the other destroys is failing (any `before_destroy/after_destroy` callbacks?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the stack trace... beware of using names like Association.

In ActiveRecord there's already an Association class
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb

Comment: Stupid me, didn't think for a second about that ... thanks a million. Changed the name of the model/controller and everything went perfect.